# Second hand Macbook and Find My Mac

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro, find-my-mac

Quick question:

- Bought a secondhand Macbook pro over ebay.
- Seller told me "I logged off from iCloud but forgot to turn off Find My Mac.
- Bought it anyway since I do not plan using iCloud.
- Now I got news that if he wants he can track and block my Mac.

I have administrator account access, the EFI is not password protected since i asked him to wipe it out, so:

Can I simply log in with my iCloud account to the Mac and disable Find My Mac?

It's not nice to know that somebody can "track me".

More info:

The seller formated the drive before sending it to me, when i turned it off i got to the first time installation wizard. There's no apple id associated to the macbook and the only user is the one i did create in the wizard and has no icloud account associated whatsoever.

So, is it even possible to log off from your icloud account without disabling "find my mac"?. i've read that the tokes for find my mac are stored in nvram and the recovery partition so a hard drive format is quite useless since the device would be still showing up in the "find" icloud account of the seller.

Comment: Do you mean "Find My Mac"? If he really meant that he did not turn off Find My iPhone, you are fine. Find My iPhone tracks iPhones; Find My Mac tracks Macs.

Comment: Sorry, in fact it is "find my mac". can i disable it by logging into my iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

Computers, phones, and devices that are **not currently logged in** with a given Apple ID *and* specifically with the service Find My Mac / Find My iPhone enabled will show up as "Offline" in someone's iCloud account etc.

So, basically, if both of you have the same computer in your iCloud accounts with Find My Mac, only the person who is currently logged in can track it. If neither of you are logged in no one can track it. The only way he could track it at this point is if you knew his Apple ID and password and went into System Preferences > iCloud and set-up Find My Mac for him. It is up to him if he wants to keep a line in his iCloud.com menu under Find My Mac that has the "name" of the computer that was retrieved the last time he tracked it that will perpetually search and always fail to find your computer, and just say "Offline". You can't change that for him.

You're safe. With the computer wiped, his user account isn't present, and that's where the iCloud account data is stored. You do not need to track your computer to "block" him from doing. It's just up to you if you want to track it at all for yourself. He will never know where it is again.

Comment: The macbook came wiped out, i got to the installation wizard the first time i turned it on. if i log into my icloud account and turn on "find my mac", will it still show up in the sellers icloud account?

Comment: Not in a useful way. I will revise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Might be late for this. But if you reset the NVRAM holding the keys <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> immediately after turning the Mac on, *Find my Mac* is going to be turned off. Make sure you hear the "startup chime" at least twice to confirm the NVRAM has been reset :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely correct. You can put a new iCloud user and the old iCloud user can not track your Mac. But if you get access in partition recovery, the old user still are here and if in other moment he blocked your Mac, it will be blocked, or erased.

If you get access to recovery partition be sure turn off Wi-Fi. If you need reinstall OS X vía Wi-Fi can be dangerous.